# Many to Many but add one more column how to do it?

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

[image: Pojo]

it creates the business_handled table but I need to add one more column in the business_handled table.

I need to add a "Role" column which contains "Owner", "Manager", "Encoder".

any ideas? I've been searching for a while can't find the solution

Comment: where is the information of Role in your Java classes?????? JPA can only persist what is in the class

Answer (score 1):

Jpa doesn't support this feature ...  The only solution is to make the business_handled another entity with one to many relationship with each of business and user entities and add whatever atreibute u need inside